# Why doesn't my bouncy ball program stop after the 5th bounce?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I nested a for loop inside a while to keep track of the time. And the while loop keeps track of the bounces if a certain condition is met. As long as that condition is met the for loop will keep counting. But once the condition is met the loop is suppose to stop. However, it continues regardless of the condition inside the while loop.

```
/*
     * @Author Lawton C Mizel
     * @Version 1.0, 07 October 2014
     * 
     * A program that simulates a ball bouncing by computing 
     * its height in feet and each "second" as time passes on 
     * a simulated clock.
     * 
*/
public class bouncyballs001 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create and connect scanner object
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        //introduce program
        System.out.println("Welcome to the bouncing ball program!");

        //prompts the user
        System.out.println("Please enter the initial velocity: ");

        double vel = keyboard.nextInt();

        //initial variables

        double height = 0;
        int bounce = 0;
        while (bounce < 5) {
            for (int time = 0; time <= 30; time++) //counter
            {
                if (time >= 0) {
                    height = height + vel;
                    vel = vel - 32.0;
                }

                if (height < 0) {
                    height = height * -0.5;
                    vel = vel * -0.5;
                    System.out.println("BOUNCE!");
                    bounce++;
                }
                System.out.println("time: " + time + " " + "height: " + height);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not reaching the outer while loop until time has incremented 30 times. You can add the bounce requirement to the for loop and remove the while loop. What's happening is you can bounce 30 times in the for loop before bounce is checked in the outer while loop.

```
    for(int time=0; time <= 30 && bounce < 5; time++) //counter, bails out if bounce > 5
    {
        if(time >= 0)
        {
        height = height + vel;
        vel = vel - 32.0;
        }

        if(height < 0)
        {
            height = height * -0.5;
            vel = vel * -0.5;
            System.out.println("BOUNCE!");
            bounce++;
        }
        System.out.println("time: "+time+" "+"height: "+height);
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use an if statement and `break`.

Answer (score 1):

You have bounce++ in a conditional that will never get called.

```
if (height < 0)
```

will never be true because height starts at 0 and goes up (i.e. can never be negative).

This means that bounce will never be anything but 0.

Comment: But vel can be negative so height too, isn't it ?

Comment: velocity can be negative, however I am assuming the height will not be negative as that would mean it is below the ground, therefore this if statement will never get reached.

Comment: height can be negative. Try using 16 as velocity and running through 4 loops.

Comment: I suppose my initial assumption was the beginning reference point that the height was being compared to was the ground the ball is bouncing on (which would be height = 0).